# iPhone send bluetooth message to others users with app installed

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, message

If I click a button in "Awesome App", is there any way to send a short text message to nearby users who also have "Awesome App" installed?  This could be via bluetooth, wifi, 3g or any other way you smart people can suggest.

Comment: It depends whether you want the other person with Awesome App to be expecting and to launch the app and put it in a state ready to receive?

Comment: no they wouldn't be expecting it, and may not even know the user sending the message.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the app for geo updates, submit the location to your server and when the user sends a message this message will be send to your server, the location is checked and all nearby users receive a push notification with this message.

Also make sure that they can fetch the message from the server as well, as push notification delivery isn't guaranteed.

To update the location of the app you call

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

If you don't need updates anymore, make sure to call

```
[self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

Also make sure to set the `location` value in the `info.plist`'s `UIBackgroundModes` key.

This will give you locations changes while your app is in the background and, according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges), will even restart your app if it has been terminated.

Comment: hmm yeah I was thinking something along these lines.  So is it possible to keep sending the user's location off to my server, even if my app is in the background or completely closed?  Thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer above! Note that this will only work in a multitasking enabled environment, but that shouldn't be a problem anymore!

Comment: thanks mate - appreciate your time.